# Which TCP/IP layer does web proxy operate in and is my understanding of implementation correct?

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy

Let's say client C wants to send HTTP request to server S, but through proxy P.

How I understand it is that it is done with just the following two modifications to the plain HTTP request:

1. The client sends the regular HTTP message, just with the full URL (in the first line of the HTTP message) rather than relative, and adds proxy-specific headers if necessary. The proxy processes and removes proxy-specific headers. This is the application layer operation.
2. This message is sent to the TCP/IP address of the proxy, and not that of the server. The proxy makes the request to the TCP/IP address of the server (which is found in the first line of the HTTP message). This is the TCP/IP layers operation.

Therefore I would say that proxying is done at IP, TCP and application layers.

Is the above correct?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Good edit. Your title could use some attention as the question itself does not seem to be asking *how* a proxy is implemented in the TCP/IP stack. (and I would discourage asking only "how" as that would again make your Q too broad.)

Comment: it has been a while but that sounds about right.. You write "This is the TCP/IP layers operation."   That is rather meaningless though.  You say "proxying is done at IP, TCP and application layers"   Well, HTTP Proxying, yes I suppose so, though has been a while.

Comment: A)somebody could try to complicate what you're saying  with i)a socks proxy  ii)an https proxy , without first and foremost telling you whther you're correct re what you are talking about. i.e. plain http proxy. (not ssl, no socks), though I think those would also be IP,TCP,and App layer.  B)You should set up a proxy with e.g. analogx or ccproxy, and use wireshark(a packet sniffer) and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Also  you have conflated specific protocols with the name of the layer. So, in the OSI reference scheme, it's Network layer,  Transport Layer, Application Layer.   IP is one protocol at the network layer but a network could run IPX.  Also any real thing would work at lower layers too like physical layer, and data link layer.  One particular protocol one might say is often one particular layer, (with perhaps some exceptions like ARP).  Or maybe a  cisco router or many, might not touch other layers.. but often real things work on other layers.

Comment: So, if the packet and  I mean packet in the general sense of what is sent, if the packet is going to have to travel to another computer, then something is going to have to work at the physical and data link layers.. a switch would work at the data link layer.. And if you monitored your packet you'd see the frame change, the data link layer.. But it'd be from a network switch.

Comment: @barlop Consider regular HTTP proxy. OFC computer will work at physical and data link layers, but this is irrelevant to proxy operation. The question is which operations at which layers make proxy operation as opposed to (or in addition to) regular HTTP.

Comment: @croraf well, HTTP is not a layer it's a protocol at a layer. I tcan agree with you that we can rule out physical layer and data link layer    So that only leaves  Network Layer, Transport Layer, Application Layer.    Clearly the proxy works at the Network Layer.  Now what of the other layers, well, you rightly mention that it looks at HTTP Headers, so clearly it works at the Application Layer.And then what of the Transport layer, well, maybe that is dealt with by the Operating System.Like the proxy program will rely heavily on operating system calls to get the transport layer sorted, and that

Comment: (cnt) would really be considered to be part of the proxy program. 'cos there's no special name like "Transporter" for the thing that deals with TCP.  Also, I think perhaps if you have something operating on multiple layers then I don't think the layers terminology isn't that useful. It's good for network engineers to distinguish hubs routers and switches though! I'm not sure how useful it is outside of that

Comment: I didnt use HTTP term as a layer. When I said "regular HTTP", I meant "HTTP through proxy" request as opposed to "regular HTTP without proxy". By transport I meant that it can use different port when contacting proxy then the port the proxy will use to access the server?

Comment: @croraf  There's a difference between HTTP and Web Proxy.   If you mean "HTTP Through a proxy" and you say "Regular HTTP", when asking about layers, then it's extremely unclear, because HTTP is a protocol at the application layer.  A Web Proxy would I suppose (usually at least), operate on three layers as you said. However, I can think of a case of a Web Proxy that would operate only at the Application Layer.   Just as some firewalls are transparent,  (i.e. not seen as a hop). So too, a web proxy could be configured as transparent, and it could just change HTML.